# Trying to open gamescene in xcode 9.2 on vmware MAC High Sierra but xcode unexpectedlly shut down

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.2

I am trying to open Gamescene.sks file in Vmware HighSierra Mac but XCode unexpectedly closes. I have the solution for XCode 8. How to do for Xcode 9.2?

Comment: If your project and your SKS does not have any problems, I think your issue is related to VMWare video drivers and the current Xcode and you should focus your attention to your virtual operating system and the video drivers kexts loaded..

Comment: Any errors or log files?

Answer (score 0):

As **AlessandroOrnano** pointed out, the problem could be due to the video drivers. Since `SpriteKit` uses GPU, and VMWare cannot use GPU acceleration for macOS, there will be glitches and stuttering wherever the system uses graphics that runs on GPU such as `VisualEffect` views, rendering 2D or 3D objects in a scene etc. VMWare uses **3D software rendering** for all graphics-related activities in macOS, and the fact that `SpriteKit` needs **Hardware acceleration** can make it not work at all or crash.